# How to tie a some controls on one view model

Tags: wpf

I have a view model with some fields, i.e.

`type ViewModel =
    member x.a = [1;2;3]
    member x.b = [4;5;6]
    member x.c = [7]`

and in WPF application places some views, as:

```
<Control.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTempl">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTempl">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTempl}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Control.Resources>

                <StackPanel>
                    <TabControl x:Name="ListBoxViewPresenter">
                        <TabItem Header="vm.a" Content="{Binding vm.a}" 
                             ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTempl}"/>
                        <TabItem Header="vm.b" Content="{Binding vm.b}" 
                             ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTempl}"/>
                        <TabItem Header="vm.c" Content="{Binding vm.c}" 
                             ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTempl}"/>
                    </TabControl>
                    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxViewPresenter">
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding vm.a}" 
                                     ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTempl}" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding vm.b}" 
                                     ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTempl}" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding vm.c}" 
                                     ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTempl}" />
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
```

What should I do to achieve such behavior:
when you clicked on some element in vm.a/b/c in ListBoxViewPresenter so same element in ListBoxViewPresenter is must selected in corresponding TabItem.

UPD:
Specifically my real problem, changing from origin topic.

I have ViewModel with fields: onelines, twolines... and a field with name selected_scheme.
In xaml:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=name}" x:Name="ProjectArea">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Однониточные планы" Style="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding onelines}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SchemeWrapperTemplate}" />
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Двухниточные планы" Style="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding twolines}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SchemeWrapperTemplate}" />
                    </TreeViewItem>
```

And data template:

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SchemeWrapperTemplate">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding schemes}" 
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SchemeTemplate}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding selected_scheme}">
                <ListBox.Style>
```

In other place of the program:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding selected_scheme.path}" />
                </Grid>
```

And when you click on some ListBoxes then selected item not changing if you click on a yet SelectedItems.

Comment: I don't get it.. the "selected item" is not changing but why would it change ? It should already be equal to the ListBox's SelectedItem since it is bound to it ?

Comment: The selected_item field is one for all ListBoxes. In my code you can see two ListBoxes builded on template "SchemeWrapperTemplate" - Content="{Binding onelines}" and Content="{Binding twolines}". When I click on some element in first listbox then selected_item changes, then I click on some element in second listbox and selected_item also changes, but when after it I click on already selected item in first listbox - nothing changes. And it expected but I would not want to keep track of active ListBox. Is there an easier way?

Comment: An easier way to do what ? What do you want to achieve exactly ? Do you just want to be notified when the user clicks on a item ?

Comment: I want to change the one field in ViewModel from different ListBoxes :) For example in ViewModel I have three fields: List<int>{1;2} named A and List<int>{3} named B and Object filed named SI. In a WPF there is bounds to these fields: ListBox( ItemsSource = A; SelectedItem = SI) and ListBox( ItemsSource = B; SelectedItem = SI).  In WPF: I click on field 1(SE <- 1) then click on field 3(SE <- 3) then click on field 1(SE <- 1 not happening). How to achieve a behavior when performed last step in scheme: (SE <- 1; SE <- 3; SE <- 1)

Comment: Sorry for my English. I have so litle practice in it and may be express thoughts not correct.

Comment: I added a new answer to solve your new problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer after you edited :

It does not make much sense to bind the same object to the SelectedItem property of two different lists that contain different elements. You have to redesign your application or you may be confronted to many problems due to this strange design in the futur.

Still, you can achieve want you want to do with a little codebehing. When the user clicks on one of your ListBox, you set the selected item of your other listbox to null. Then you will be notified when you re-click on the first listbox since the selection goes from null to something.

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxViewPresenter"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentlySelectedItem}" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}" />
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxViewPresenter2"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentlySelectedItem}" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource2}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

codebehind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication13
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        private object _currentlySelectedItem;

        public object CurrentlySelectedItem
        {
            get { return _currentlySelectedItem; }

            set
            {
                _currentlySelectedItem = value;

                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentlySelectedItem"));
                }
            }
        }

        private List<int> _myItemsSource = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

        private List<int> _myItemsSource2 = new List<int> { 3, 4 };

        public List<int> MyItemsSource
        {
            get { return _myItemsSource; }
            set { _myItemsSource = value; }
        }


        public List<int> MyItemsSource2
        {
            get { return _myItemsSource2; }
            set { _myItemsSource2 = value; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;

            ListBoxViewPresenter.PreviewMouseDown += ListBoxViewPresenter_PreviewMouseDown;
            ListBoxViewPresenter2.PreviewMouseDown += ListBoxViewPresenter2_PreviewMouseDown;
        }

        void ListBoxViewPresenter_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxViewPresenter2.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        void ListBoxViewPresenter2_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxViewPresenter.SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the template of ListBoxItem from a simple TextBlock to a Button with command that takes a ListBoxItem's data context as parameter and set it to selected_item of my ViewModel's.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should define the `ItemsSource` of your `TabItem` and `ListBox` in the `ViewModel` they are bound too.
Then you can bind their `SelectedItem` to a property in your ViewModel.

Here is a code sample (I was too lazy to create a seperate ViewModel class, hence it is mixed with my main window class, but you get the idea...) :

Codebehind :

```
namespace WpfApplication13
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private object _currentlySelectedItem;

        public object CurrentlySelectedItem
        {
            get { return _currentlySelectedItem; }

            set
            {
                _currentlySelectedItem = value;

                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentlySelectedItem"));
                }
            }
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            public string MyString { get; set; }

            public MyClass(string myString)
            {
                this.MyString = myString;
            }
        }

        private List<MyClass> _myItemsSource = new List<MyClass>
                                               { 
                                                  new MyClass("toto"),
                                                  new MyClass("tata") 
                                               };

        public List<MyClass> MyItemsSource
        {
            get { return _myItemsSource; }
            set { _myItemsSource = value; }
        }

        public object A
        {
            get { return "toto"; }
        }

        public object B
        {
            get { return "tata"; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TabControl x:Name="ListBoxViewPresenter"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentlySelectedItem}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}" />
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxViewPresenter2"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentlySelectedItem}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without set a ItemsSource?

Comment: @psct Yes, you can manually add or remove items in the codebehind using ListBoxViewPresenter2.Items.Add() for example, but unless you have a very good reason to do so I strongly recommend the use of ItemsSource.

Comment: Ok, as it turned out my problem is not solved by this. I have some ListBoxes with bindings for some lists in ViewModel and when one of their item is selecting I wish to change "selected_item" field in my ViewModel. But if in one ListBox named A I select a some field then in other ListBox did the same and then in ListBox "A" click on yet selected item a now SelectedItem does not change and "selected_item"  does not change.